# Is it possible to simulate a call with espresso tests?

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing, android-uiautomator

Just wondering if it's possible to simulate a call (user receives a call, answers and then clicks certain UI buttons like mute etc) with espresso tests? 
I have heard of UIAutomator for that, but not really sure how to go about it, any examples or ideas on how to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using an Emulator and below adb command,

```
$ adb -s <serialno> shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d tel:555-5555
```

In your espresso code, try following method to invode adb command,

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
process.waitFor();
```